# turn off and on notifications when app is completely closed

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification, uiswitch, onesignal

I have installed OneSiganl in my project and I the way to turn off the local Notification is:
`OneSignal.setSubscription(false)`
and also I added 
`UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()`

Now I have a switch and I'm saving the state of the switch in NSUserDefaults when the switch is OFF

```
if NSUserDefaults.state == "OFF"{
`OneSignal.setSubscription(false)`

 `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()`
}

if NSUserDefaults.state == "ON"{
`OneSignal.setSubscription(true)`

}
```

My question is when the user closes the app completely, will he/she receive notifications if sent from my server ? and if the user turn on the switch will they receive notifications ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UNUserNotificationCenter.current().removeAllPendingNotificationRequests()` removes only local scheduled notifications. If you correctly registered for the remote notifications (and I assume that OneSignal does this for you along with instructions for you how to set app permissions and user messages upon request permission, I'm not familiar with the framework though) then the answer for your question is: yes.

Comment: Right. I tested it and OneSignal does remove all the notifications even when the app is closed